# Knowing mean, standard deviation and population size, calculate guaranteed number of elements in range

Tags: self-study

Knowing the true mean, the true standard deviation and the number of elements of a given population (without knowing the actual values), is it possible to calculate the **guaranteed** number of elements in a given range? (for example, guaranteed number of elements in [μ - 2σ,μ + 2σ])

The distribution type is unknown.

The question is related to a university task I am trying to solve, but have no idea if this approach is viable or not.

Comment: You are on the track of an important idea in statistical inference, but statistical inference does not usually offer absolute guarantees.

Comment: If by "guaranteed" you mean *minimum,* then look up Chebyshev's Inequality.  Otherwise, could you clarify what you mean by "guaranteed"?

Comment: Becouse there are infinite solutions, by guaranteed I mean the minimum number of items that must be inside the interval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Chebyshev's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality) guarantees that no more than 1/k^2 of the distribution's values can be more than k standard deviations away from the mean.

For example, given the following data:

- μ: 170
- σ: 8
- Population Size: 440
- Range: [154, 176] --> [μ - 2σ,μ + 2σ]

Applying Chebyshev's Inequality, we get that no more than 1/4 of the elements (110) can be outside the range, so we can guarantee that at least 1 - (1/4)  elements (330) will be inside the range.

Thanks to whuber for pointing me in the correct direction.

Answer (score 0):

If the population distribution is normal, then *about* 95% of the $n$ observations
should lie in the interval $\mu \pm 1.96\sigma$ because for any one observation $X,$
$$P(\mu - 1.96\sigma < X < \mu + 1.96\sigma) = P\left(-1.96 < \frac{X-\mu}{\sigma} < 1.96\right) = P(-1.96 < Z < 1.96) = 0.95,$$
where $Z$ has a standard normal distribution. But there is ***no guarantee*** as to the exact number out of $n$ observations that will fall in this interval.

Furthermore, according to the *Central Limit Theorem,* if $\bar X = \frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ is the *sample* mean of
a large number $n$ of observations from a population with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma,$ then $$P\left(\bar X - 1.96\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} < \mu < \bar X + 1.96\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}\right) = 0.95,$$
so we say that $\bar X \pm 1.96\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$ is a 95% 'confidence interval' for $\mu.$ The number $n$ that qualifies as 'large enough' depends
on the shape of the population distribution. Over the long run, an interval
of the type $\bar X \pm 1.96\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$ will include the true
population mean $\mu$ in 95% of instances, but *no guarantee* can be given
for any one particular 95% confidence interval.